# I need to select the "slides" from each segment

Tags: ionic-framework

I'm new to Angular and Ionic. I'm trying to create an element that when I choose a segment value, it appears a different ion-slides.
This is the code I have tried so far.

```
<ion-segment value="Value 1" (ionChange)="segmentChanged(cat)" >
  <ion-segment-button value="cat.value" *ngFor="let cat of items">
    <ion-label>{{cat.category}}</ion-label>
  </ion-segment-button>
</ion-segment>

<ion-slides  [options]="sliderConfig">
  <ion-slide *ngFor="let product of cat.products">
    <ion-card>
      <ion-card-header>
        <ion-card-title>{{product.name}} </ion-card-title>
        <ion-card-content>
          <ion-button expand="full">Item</ion-button>
        </ion-card-content> 
      </ion-card-header>
    </ion-card>
  </ion-slide>
</ion-slides>
```

However I don't know how to select the value of the segment, because the ngFor is inside the segment-buttons. I also don't know how can I can choose the "Slides" I need to show. In the example I showed previously, each slide is a product from an specific category.

Answer (score 0):

try this one to get the segment value :

```
  <ion-segment (ionChange)="segmentChanged($event)">
      <ion-segment-button *ngFor="let cat of items" value={{cat.value}} >
        <ion-label>{{cat.category}}</ion-label>
      </ion-segment-button>
</ion-segment>
```

inside the ts file :

```
segmentChanged(ev) {
    console.log(ev.value)
  }
```

Comment: But then I can't "choose" the slides I want from the different values